# How to update data in Laravel controller?

Tags: php, laravel, sql-update, laravel-controller

I am trying to update my template details in the controller. But currently, my code is not working. It is not updating the fields. Anyhow if I add $template->save(). It saves the updated record as a new record. How to make my current code work? Why I am facing this situation? Please, someone, explain to me and correct my code as still, I am learning Laravel. Thanks in advance.

**update function in TemplateController**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        if(! lara_club_has_permission('edit-template') ){
            return view('403');
        }

        $this->validate($request, [
                'title'=>'required',
                'start_date'=> 'required',
                'end_date'=>'required',
                'template_content'=>'required',
            ]
        );

        //check status response
        if(isset($request->status)&&$request->status=='on'){
            $status='1';
        }else{
            $status="0";
        } 

        $template=new Template();

        $template->title=$request->title;
        $template->start_date=convert_to_sql_date_format($request->start_date);
        $template->end_date=convert_to_sql_date_format($request->end_date);
        $template->is_active=$status;
        $template->template_content=$request->template_content;

        $input = $request->all();

        $template->update($input);

        $name = $input['title'];

        return redirect()->route('templates.index')->with('success', 'Template <b>'. $name.'</b> Updated!');
    }
```

Comment: you should add the condition for where to update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you creating new object `$template=new Template();` 
but you need to update existing one so try below code

```
        $template=Template::find($id);
        //or use $template=Template::where('id',$id)->first();

        $template->title=$request->title;
        $template->start_date=convert_to_sql_date_format($request->start_date);
        $template->end_date=convert_to_sql_date_format($request->end_date);
        $template->is_active=$status;
        $template->template_content=$request->template_content;

        $input = $request->all();

        $template->update($input);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use Laravel `find` method, instead of declaring a new instance of it.

It should be

```
$template=Template::find($id);
```

Not

```
$template=new Template();
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I specify the table name in the method name, like this.

```
public function update(Request $request, Template $id)
{
    $id->title=$request->title;
    $id->start_date=convert_to_sql_date_format($request->start_date);
    $id->end_date=convert_to_sql_date_format($request->end_date);
    $id->is_active=$status;
    $id->template_content=$request->template_content;

    $input = $request->all();

    $id->update($input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case , I am using  like this..

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
            $employee = Employee::find($id);

            $employee->name=$request->name;
            $employee->email=$request->email;
            $employee->phone=$request->phone;

            $input = $request->all();
            $employee->update($input);
           //$validated = $this->validateEmployee($request);
           //Employee::update($validated);
           return response()->json('Data Updated');
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please note that your case is quite different from the OPs question (there's no `$employee` there). Also, the main point, that using `find($id);` instead of `new` has already been pointed out.